# Angularjs Scope of Variable inside of function

Tags: html, angularjs

Following structure inside my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="anbieter">Anbieter</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="fields_answers.address" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I want to fill in data from my database with a `$http.get` inside my controller which looks like the following (only the important stuff):

```
(function(){
var SubmitFormController = angular.module('bdb').controller('submitFormCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $window, $location, $http, $sce){
    var submitForm = this;
    $scope.fields_answers = {};

    submitForm.showResult = function(){
      $http.get("api/administration/idSearch/" + document.getElementById('searchFieldId').value, true).success(function (response) {
        $scope.fields_answers.address = response[0][0].address;
      });
    };
}());
```

So when I try to set something with $scope.fields_answers.address **outside** of the `showResult()` function it works, but I can't seem to access the ng-model variable inside the showResult function, it doesn't seem to be visible.

**Edit**:
I've tried adding an id="address" to the input and set it inside the showResult() function with

```
 document.getElementById('address').value = response[0][0].address;
```

**this works**.
But I want (**have**) to use the ng-model variable.

Comment: I think your http request doesnt work, try to have an error callback (check link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and debug the request

Comment: I should've been more precise: the ´$http.get´ works 100% (checked with console.log) and setting ´$scope.fields_answers.address´ = 'something' outside of the function works as well. It is possible to set an id=address and set the variable with document.getElementById('adresse').value = response[0][0].address; but I don't want to do it like that, I want to use angular

Comment: Console.log `response`???

Comment: So for the next step, try to set `$scope.fields_answers.address = 'somevalue';`

Comment: And again: the http.get works and setting $scope.fields_answers.address to some test value works as well.... But not **inside** the submitForm.showResult function

Comment: if you want to bind it using ng-model in your html, just do this (lets say its an input type) <input type="text" data-ng-model="fields_answers.address"/>

Comment: So have you tried setting the scope inside the submitForm to a static value and it worked?

Comment: Where are you calling your http get function? @Buitenlander

Comment: @Rahul Arora: I've changed ng-model to data-ng-model, still not working

Comment: Make sure you called `showResult` function.

Comment: @Rahul Arora: line 7 $http.get(.....)

Comment: How you are adding controller to HTML, is it using controllerAs ?

Comment: You are not calling the function submitForm.showResult it seems @Buitenlander

Comment: @WorkWe: If I wouldn't call the showResult function, how would I be able to set the value with document.getElementById('adresse').value = 'test' inside the showResult() function ?

Comment: @Rahul Arora: Yes, I am.

Comment: Give us HTML code of form to call `showResult` function?

Comment: Can you check your network tab to see if this API call is even going through, either you have shared in complete code and if this is your full code, you then need to call the function like submitForm.showResult();

Comment: Please see my edit in the original question: showResult() is called 100%, the controller works 100% everything works, except for this

Comment: In your code example you use `'adresse'` once and `.address` you should stick to one lang
And you still havent answered if you can set the `$scope` to a static value INSIDE the function.

Comment: The API call is going through, I wouldn't be able to set it with document.getElementById('address').value = 'test' (if I added id="address" to the input)

Comment: @SeRu: fixed the "adresse" to "address" (I've just translated it for you guys and overlooked it once, sorry). Do you mean by a static value just some string like $scope.fields_answers.address = "hello" ? this doesn't work either.

Comment: Try this in the function `$scope.test = 'testvalue'; console.log($scope.test);` and check the console for the log.

Comment: @SeRu: console.log gives me `testvalue`, so this works

Comment: Now try to set the `$scope.test = response[0][0].address` and again check the log.

Comment: @SeRu: this gives the correct value found in `response[0][0].address` (correct value from the database).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113489/discussion-between-seru-and-buitenlander).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to your issue or not, but the use of success on $http.get is deprecated. Try changing success to then.

Then returns a full response object so your data should be on the data member of the response meaning you would access it with response.data and then usually when there are multiple values they will be in a values array off of data, so probably response.data.values[0][0].address.

If that's a bit off, output response to the console and adjust accordingly and if necessary, post what the response object looks like here.